# Metric (like) should be specified with metric_type=total_value

Tags: python, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to use a curl request to get the likes from my Instagram account but I keep getting the same error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) The following metrics (likes) should be specified with parameter metric_type=total_value","type":"OAuthException","code":100
```

My code is given below:

```
curl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/ig-business-account-id/insights?metric=impressions,reach,likes&period=day&access_token='
response = requests.get(curl)
print (response.text)
```

I've tried to search what total_value means but I can't find anything in the documentation about how to use it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Fakhr , did you manage to performe this API call? I'm facing the same issue and the documentation doesn't mention any of this. Thanks!

Comment: Hey guys! @Barbi 
Did you manage to make this work ? I'm facing the exact same problem in v15.0

Comment: Hi @RoHiguera unfortunately not, sorry! Still waiting for some hints or facebook's updated docs